# AngularJS - What's the best way to submit only values of "relevant" form fields?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a form with some fields that are only relevant/displayed under certain condition. What's the best way to prevent these fields from being submitted if they're hidden/irrelevant?

E.g.

```
<form name="fm">
  <div><input name="field1" ng-model="data.field1"/></div>
  <div ng-if="data.field1=='1'"><input name="field2" ng-model="data.field2"/></div>
</form>
```

What's the best way to prevent the value of `field2` from being submitted if `data.field1='2'`?

The only way I can think of is to loop through each and every item in `$scope.data` and manually remove them if the corresponding field is missing from the dom.

Comment: You will not be able to really do so in the HTML. But, you can pass all values into a function on submit and remove the values based on logic in the controller (which is where that logic belongs)

Comment: You could use the ngSubmit directive to handle that logic in a given controller before sending it to a server.  Either that or separate forms.

Comment: Basically both suggestions are what I had in mind :). That's cool, just wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking any built-in angular feature that can achieve the same goal in a more elegant way.

Comment: This is not possible, but you can write a click directive where you can remove this. can you give a plunker where i can edit.

Comment: @Shohel It's ok I've got it sorted :). Thanks anyway.